# Get img width from a div full of img's: z-index & opacity are deciding factors

Tags: javascript, z-index, element, image, opacity

I have the following code in my page.

```
<div id="divId">
  <img src="somePic0.png" style="z-index:10; opacity:0;"/>
  <img src="somePic1.png" style="z-index:9; opacity:0;"/>
  <img src="somePic2.png" style="z-index:8; opacity:1;"/> <!-- need the height of this! -->
  <img src="somePic3.png" style="z-index:7; opacity:1;"/>
  <img src="somePic4.png" style="z-index:6; opacity:1;"/>
</div>
```

I need to get the img height of the line commented!

Would like a jQuery solution but plain javascript is ok!

EDIT: The images property "opacity" cycles. They all begin as 1 and then gradually turn to down to 0. When they all hit zero they are all set to 1 again. Then they "count down" again. The purpose of this div is to cycle background images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add classes to each of the nodes, iterate through them then collect the relevant information you need from it.

```
    <div id="divId">
        <img class="node" src="somePic0.png" style="z-index:10; opacity:0;"/>
        <img class="node" src="somePic1.png" style="z-index:9; opacity:0;"/>
        <img class="node" src="somePic2.png" style="z-index:8; opacity:1;"/> 
        <img class="node" src="somePic3.png" style="z-index:7; opacity:1;"/>
        <img class="node" src="somePic4.png" style="z-index:6; opacity:1;"/>
   </div>

    <script>
        /** 
         *  var collectNodes = document.getElementById('divId').children; 
         *     for <= IE8. (Thanks Kolink)
        **/ 
        var collectNodes = document.getElementsByClassName('node');
        var y = 0;
        for ( var x = 0; x < collectNodes.length; x++ ) {
            if ( collectNodes[x].style.opacity !== "" && !y ) {
                y = x;
            }
        }
        console.log ( collectNodes[y].style.opacity );
        console.log ( collectNodes[y].height );
   </script>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XHr3P/3/

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is not supported in IE8 and below, and is completely redundant in this case since `document.getElementById('divId').children` will get you the exact same nodes.

Comment: I did some changes, but you got me on the right track thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If the image's position is what defines it (ie. you want the third image), try this:

```
 var height = document.getElementById('divId').children[2].height;
```

If you want the one that has a `z-index` of 8, try this:

```
 var height = (function(c) {
     var l = c.length, i;
     for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
         if( c[i].style.zIndex == 8) return c[i].height;
     }
 })(document.getElementById('divId').children);
```

And if you're looking for the first opaque image, try this:

```
 var height = (function(c) {
     var l = c.length, i;
     for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
         if( c[i].style.opacity == 1) return c[i].height;
     }
 })(document.getElementById('divId').children);
```

Comment: Ah sorry, wasn't 100% clear: The opacity cycles. So when they all turn 0, they all turn 1, then they gradually "count" down to 0 again!

Answer (score 0):

can't you add a class to those imgs? or an ID?

if not, you can do it with jQuery

```
$("img[src='" + nameofthe pic + "']").width()
```

edit:

To get the width of the highest z-index and opacity you'll need to iterate over the images and compare the css to get the one you want...
I think this would do it...

```
var z_index = 0;
var $img;

    $.each($("imgs selector"), function(i, e){
        if($(e).css("opacity") == 1){
            if ($(e).css("z-index") > z_index){
                z_index = $(e).css("z-index");
                $img = $(e);
            }

        }
    });


    $img.width();
```

Comment: I could do that, but how would I get the img width of the img with the highest z-index with opacity of 1?

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you would prefer a jQuery solution, I'll throw in one way to do it using jQuery. I've created a tiny jQuery plugin that will return the element with opacity set to `1` and with the highest z-index.

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.getHighestVisibleZ = function() {
    var highestZ, $elm;
    this.filter(function (){
       return $(this).css("opacity") === "1";
    }).each(function(){
        var z = parseInt($(this).css("zIndex"), 10);
        if (!highestZ || highestZ < z) {
           highestZ = z;
           $elm = $(this);
        }
    });
    return $elm;
  };
})( jQuery );


// You could now use the plugin like so    
console.log($("#divId img").getHighestVisibleZ().width());
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wDJXs/)

*Notice that z-index only apply to elements that aren't static, so for this to work your images have to have a position other than static.*

Answer (score -1):

Here is my prefered way

```
var index = 2;
var width;
$("img").each(function(arg){
    if(index==arg){
      width = $(this).width();
    }  
});
```

here is the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/UNPpL/2/

Comment: You do realise your "preferred way" is a long and convoluted way of just doing `width = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[index].width;`, right?

Comment: not really, by the index I do not mean img element sequence, img source named index could be random like somePic1.png, somePic5.png, somePic0.png